# How to use maxlength on textarea in struts 1 html tag

Tags: tags, struts-1

In struts 1 tags for html:textarea [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#textarea)

I do not see a maxlength attribute. How can i restrict the user from entering more than 100 characters? Also why did struts 1 omit such a basic attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this "basic attribute" wasn't even supported in IE before IE10, and was added in HTML 5.

Struts 1 predates that by a significant margin, has been EOL'd, and hasn't seen a new release for some time. Bear in mind that Struts 1.2's last release was, what, 2006-ish?

You may extract the TLD and modify it to allow arbitrary attributes under JSP 2.0:

```
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the attribute using JS.

Put something like this after your textarea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('textarea-id').setAttribute('maxlength', '512');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. add `styleId` attribute to the `html:textarea`, struts will not accept `id` attribute.
2. add Javascript to limit the length after that

   ```
   <html:textarea styleId="contactText" property="contactText" cols="55" rows="10"/>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('contactText').setAttribute('maxlength', '10');
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score -2):

You may use `maxlength="100"` within the text area or input in JSP, or else you have to customize validator.xml.

In validator.xml:

```
<field property="propertyname" depends="maxlength">
              <var-name>maxlength</var-name>
                    <var-value>100</var-value>
                  </var>
                  <msg key="propertyname.maxlength" name="maxlength" />
</field>
```

In Application.proprties:

```
propertyname.maxlength = <tr><td colspan\="2" class\="note">Please make sure that FieldName is only  maximum 100 characters.</td></tr>
```

Comment: A "maxlength" property on a div is meaningless; divs don't have length. Validation happens either on the server or client side, but doesn't stop the user from typing additional characters w/o JavaScript.